# Can't open a file in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

While opening a file in VSCode, I am facing the issue with the following message:

```
The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either in binary 
or use an unsupported text encoding
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: may help : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/29274

Answer (score 0):

VSCode 1.66 (March 2022) will help.
Its [insider version](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) includes [issue 144270](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/144270):

> ### Allow configuring the default editor for binary files

> We don't want to officially have the hex editor be recommended for non-textual files, but what about a setting like `defaultBinaryEditor` that can be used to open a binary file in a given editor instead of showing the "binary file" message?
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2230985/156430540-ce9238cb-89d0-4cb9-a1dd-9ab8901b6226.png]
>
> I would love it if I could have all non-text files automatically opened in the hex editor.

Resolution: [PR 144278](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/144278)

> ### Introduce default binary file setting
>
> This appears to be a semi-regular ask that I've previously closed.
> For binary files in particular it is often difficult to associate a glob pattern with them as it could be anything.
>
> This introduces a new setting '`workbench.defaultBinaryEditor`' which accepts an editorId to then pass into the resolver and automatically open instead of showing the binary detection message.

That way, you can have a look to this binary file content.

Comment: See also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146435